# Docker Swarm, Windows Containers, ingress network (Routing Mesh) on Windows Server 2019

Tags: docker, windows-container, docker-ingress, docker-ee

I want to build docker swarm cluster on windows. To do this I choose `Windows Server 2019` in `1809` Version. I work on my local machine and using Vagrant box `vm.box=StefanScherer/windows_2019`  I created enviroment for developing purposes.

1. Set Hostname.
2. Set private network (192.168.52.100)
3. Install Docker-EE

On this Windows I have installed docker-ee by using command `Install-Package Docker -ProviderName DockerMsftProvider -RequiredVersion 19.03 -Force`, and docker work perfectly.

1. `docker version` return everething ok
2. `docker run -it --rm -p 8000:80 --name aspnetcore_sample mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/samples:aspnetapp` -> also work perfectly.

My first issue is when I perform command `docker swarm init --advertise-addr=192.168.52.100` I notice my internet connection is lost for a while (also init/join/leave).

And the secound issue is routing mesh, it is not working

Steps to reproduce:

1. `docker service create  --publish published=8050,target=80,mode=ingress --name aspnetcore_sample mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/samples:aspnetapp`
2. Open web browser http://127.0.0.1:8050/ (on machine where I init swarm)

Now I should have access to this sample app under 8050 port. But http://127.0.0.1:8050/ is not working

I know I can use `mode=host` but I think `mode=ingress` should work.

I also checked it with the same commands on linux and it works without any problem

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: were you able to solve this somehow?

Comment: to be honest, no.
I just change windows server for a Linux based, but you can check firewall ports is open ([link](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/swarm-tutorial/#open-protocols-and-ports-between-the-hosts)), or maybe this is fixed in newer version of docker for windows?

Comment: you can track also this [topic](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/39065)

Comment: well, i gave up too :) i installed ubuntu server via hyper-v and that works perfectly